# Boost: future::then with launch::deferred policy used with async with launch::async policy

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

Let's suppose we have such code called from main thread:

```
boost::future<int> fi = boost::async(boost::launch::async, boost::bind(fun, arg));
boost::future<void> on_finish = fi.then(boost::launch::deferred, [](auto fut) {
    auto res = fut.get();
    ...
});
```

Where function `fun` has body:

```
int fun(int arg)
{
    int res;
    ...
    return res;
}
```

1. How will the work flow? Will the lambda be called from `then` continuation in main thread after execution of `fun` in other thread if main thread works purely asynchronously?
2. What will happen if main thread is busy all the time e.g. by looping in infinite loop? Will then the `then` continuation not be executed?

Comment: genuinely interesting. What did it do when you tried it?

Comment: I found out the way to test it: added line with `sleep_for` inside `fun` and some code after `.then` continuation definition. The code after the definition executed after the `fun` function, so `.then` with `launch::deferred` waits for async task to return and blocks main thread.